# What causes a Mercurial "revlog decompress error"?

Tags: mercurial

Every few hg push pull operations, the repository gets corrupted, and I get the following errors:

```
$ hg update
abort: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check!

$ hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3562: unpacking ec236be0206d: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3563: unpacking 430bb0f5162a: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3567: unpacking 4909a4b6eae1: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3601: unpacking a31db12adb94: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3605: unpacking eed043e92e13: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3624: unpacking 82712b875730: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3625: unpacking 6c8d858de500: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3626: unpacking f9ebcc4299b7: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3679: unpacking 8004dbef53aa: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3680: unpacking 9c0794be3e2b: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3683: unpacking 719d28962073: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3731: unpacking 1c6828ff0c18: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3732: unpacking 1b84208ef8a7: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 src/poisson/ep_laplace.cpp@3738: unpacking 398a5a551736: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
1648 files, 3739 changesets, 15186 total revisions
14 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 3562)
```

Comment: Where do you store that repository?

Comment: The repository is on a server. When I use TortoiseHg on my laptop I don't have any problems. The problems above occur when I'm using hg on a different server that runs CentOs.